# Error installing ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to install ruby on rails with this  [link](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04)

But getting error. When I ran this rvm install 2.3.1

I get this error

```
     mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/rvm/log/1467720951_ruby-2.3.1’: Permission denied
tee: /usr/local/rvm/log/1467720951_ruby-2.3.1/update_system.log: No such file or directory

     Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ruby-2.3.1',
    showing last 15 lines of /usr/local/rvm/log/1467720651_ruby-2.3.1/update_system.log
    tail: cannot open ‘/usr/local/rvm/log/1467720651_ruby-2.3.1/update_system.log’ for reading: No such file or directory
    Requirements installation failed with status: 1.<br/>
When i ran curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable <br/>
so it was install on /usr/local/rvm
```

When I ran ls when i was inside /usr/local/rvm getting this error
aniket@aniket.shivam-L740-X4010:/usr/local/rvm$ ls
archives  config   docs          examples   gems     help   installed.at  LICENSE  man      patchsets  RELEASE  scripts  tmp   VERSION
bin       contrib  environments  gem-cache  gemsets  hooks  lib           log      patches  README     rubies   src      user  wrappers

Comment: same error occurs when you install different ruby version?

Comment: yeah same error occurs

Comment: looks like permission issue, try `sudo rvm install` and see if it works?It's not recommended to run sudo with rvm but worth a try

Comment: sudo: rvm: command not found
getting this error

Comment: is `/usr/local/rvm/log` owned by your username?run `ls` to find out. If it is then maybe it's the Debian itself :))

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04  and have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with below command,

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local
```

then retry with

```
rvm install 2.3.1
```

Hope this will solve your problem.